# Scroll Go.js diagram when link/node is out of viewport

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a Go.js flowchart where you can drag&drop nodes from a palette and create links between them. My problem is that when I try to move a node outside the viewport bounds the diagram doesn't scroll. The same happens when I try to draw a link to a node which is outside the viewport, the diagram doesn't scroll but the link just runs out of the viewport.

Is there any implemented solution for that? When I try to drag a node from the palette to the diagram and I move it close to the viewport bounds, the diagram scrolls, I would need something similar.

Anyway, congrats on the product because it has a lot of cool functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have explicitly disabled it, the GoJS Diagram supports auto-scrolling for dragging and for linking and for relinking.

Just hold the mouse/finger down just inside the edge of the viewport.  The closer to the edge you are the faster it will scroll.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I realized that you were right. And can I set the scroll speed and the area where it starts to scroll (I tried autoScrollRegion but it didn't seem to work)?

Comment: Yes, **Diagram.autoScrollRegion** controls the auto-scroll area inside the edges of the viewport.  You can also set **Diagram.autoScrollInterval** to a number other than the default which is 250 milliseconds (undocumented).